# Auto static import in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

In below piece of code I have used Class name to import static methods in IntelliJ IDEA 2022 Community Edition

```
BDDMockito.given(employeeRepository.findByEmail(employee.getEmail()))
    .willReturn(Optional.empty());
BDDMockito.given(employeeRepository.save(employee)).willReturn(employee);
```

Is there any way or keyboard shortcut that can remove the class name and use static import like this:

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

given(employeeRepository.findByEmail(employee.getEmail()))
    .willReturn(Optional.empty());
given(employeeRepository.save(employee)).willReturn(employee);
```

I googled lot and read IntelliJ articles but could not find any solution. Any IntelliJ expert can help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may put caret on method name, press "Alt+Enter" and select "Add static import for ..."

Comment: Thanks @y.bedrov. it worked. But it resulted in 
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;
instead of import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
Is there any way to fix it.

Comment: You can probably tweak that behavior in the settings. Somewhere under code style maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your IDE to automatically import static functions/vars from specific packages with `*`.
This is the way to do it:

1. `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports (tab)`
2. Add your package name inside
   [image]

It will result in a `*` import though and you may not want this effect. But I do not know of any other way.

The good thing about this method is that the functions will be available for auto completion and that makes your life easier :)